# Best practice for creating new objects within objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have some data that is in an array that contains url's for images. Here the thing, within the img object of the data object, I want to make as many imgs as the length of the array (Make sense hopefully?). In other words, I just want to create a new object over and over again. What would you recommend as the best approach to solving this problem. I know this seems simple.

```
  var data = [{
                title: "asdfadf",
                thumb: "images/asdf.jpg",
                imgs: [{
                        title: "asdfasdf ",
                        thumb: "images/asdff.jpg",
                        img: "images/asdf.jpg",
                    },
                    {
                        title: "asdf",
                        thumb: "images/asdf.jpg",
                        img: "images/asdf.jpg",
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Gasdfafafasfasfasfasf. ",
                        thumb: "images/asdf.jpg",
                        img: "images/asdf.jpg",
                    },
                    {
                        title: "aswdf",
                        thumb: "images/asdfD.jpg",
                        img: "images/asdf.jpg",
                    },

                ]
            }];
```

Comment: This is I think is the best practice

Comment: You have extra commas all over the place

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring data as an array, declare it as an object, while keeping the declaration of the imgs property as an array:

```
  var data = {
                title: "asdfadf",
                thumb: "images/asdf.jpg",
                imgs: [{
                        title: "asdfasdf ",
                        thumb: "images/asdff.jpg",
                        img: "images/asdf.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "asdf",
                        thumb: "images/asdf.jpg",
                        img: "images/asdf.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Gasdfafafasfasfasfasf. ",
                        thumb: "images/asdf.jpg",
                        img: "images/asdf.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "aswdf",
                        thumb: "images/asdfD.jpg",
                        img: "images/asdf.jpg"
                    }

                ]
            };
```

Then, you could simply get the value of the `imgs` array property on the data object, loop over it and build up the images, for example:

```
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < data.imgs.length; i++) {

    html += 'Image title: ' + data.imgs[i].title;
    html += 'Image thumb: ' + data.imgs[i].thumb;
    html += 'Image img: ' + data.imgs[i].img + '<br>';
}

// Set the innerHtml only once, when you have built up your whole html
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHtml = html;
```

As for returning an object each time, I believe that it would be much simpler if you would return the elements of the `imgs` array instead of creating new objects. Your `imgs` array already contains the objects!

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.imgs.length; i++) {
    // This will return each object contained within the imgs array
    console.log(data.imgs[i]);
}
```

Comment: Like otherwise it's impossible? `data[0].imgs[i]`

Comment: I didn't say it was not possible :) I just wanted to offer him my own version. I believe that it is a lot better to declare an object, instead of declaring it as he did. Just my two cents! :)